# Android - is there a way to define the video resolution when taking video from application?

Tags: android, resolution, video-capture

I am not familiar with android programming,

I wish to know if there is a way to set the video resolution when it is filmed inside an android application  ?

Or, is there a way to reduce the resolution later.

We need to reduce the file size of the video that we capture.

Thanks

Shani

Comment: you can use getSupportedVideoSizes() for taking video in different size but i think there is no method available for setting video resolution

Comment: There is a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581017/android-modifying-recorded-video-quality

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are three things you can control to manage the resulting file size when recording video.  All three are available as methods in `MediaRecorder` class:

1. Frame size (width x height).  Use method `setVideoSize(int width, int height)`.  The smaller the frame size, the smaller the video file.
2. Encoding bit rate - this controls compression quality of each frame.  Use method `setVideoEncodingBitRate (int bitRate)`.  Lower bit rate results in higher compression, which in turn leads to lower quality and lower video file size.  This is only available from API level 8 and above.
3. Video "speed" - how many frames per second are captured.  Use `setVideoFrameRate (int rate)` method.  The lower the rate, the fewer frames you'll be capturing - resulting in a smaller video file size.  This is only available from API level 11 and above.  Remember though that for a smooth video you need at least 24 frames per second.

Have a look at the documentation for MediaRecorder` for more information.

Comment: I set the three things as constant but its MB data get varying  across different devices(Pixels).Is any way to fix around it.