# Android: Modifying recorded video quality

Tags: android, video

I'm using MediaRecorder to record a video. It isn't clear to me what parameters I should be using to change the quality of the image, assuming the size of the video remains constant. For example, I want to always create a 640x480 mp4 video. What parameters can I adjust to increase  or decrease the quality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using

```
recorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
recorder.setVideoFrameRate(16); //might be auto-determined due to lighting
recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);// MPEG_4_SP
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

or

```
 CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
 recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
```

For setting high quality and low quality parameter see [here](http://www.andgps.com/20110410/camcorderprofile-predefined-camcorder-profile-settings-for-camcorder-applications)

Comment: No, I cannot use that. I have to set the video manually using setVideoEncoder. I believe there are other parameters that let you specify specific values like fps, etc.. Still, not sure what parameters to set.

Comment: I just came across that as well. The post says though that it will vary among devices which means querying the capabilities. That may be the only way. Is FrameRate and BitRate the only parameters that I should be dealing with?

Comment: After experimenting, it doesn't seem like setting the FrameRate has any noticable difference. However, the BitRate does. Setting it to 300000 does create a higher quality video (of course, at the expense of file size). Are you aware of any API that can be used to determine the maximum bit rate supported by a device?

Comment: I'm not much aware of the API. Check this too.. http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations

Answer (score 0):

try this one u can solve problem

```
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT); 
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/file.mp4";
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(path);
```

Comment: Does using H264 give you a higher quality than MP4?

Comment: The setProfile actually generates an IllegalStateException. I've stayed away from using the built-in profiles after spending a day and seeing almost nothing but constant exceptions using it.

Comment: just comment those two lines of setprofile and give those parameters same as shown. u will get good quality video

Comment: That is essentially what I am doing now except the video encoder is set for MPEG_4_SP. I tried H264 but an exception will occur when recording starts. Doesn't seem like all cameras support H264. Anyway, setting the bit rate manually seems the way to go. Now if only I can figure out how to query what the maximum rate is that a device supports.

Comment: u currently using which version i mean 2.2 or else??

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase video encoding bit rate to increase the video quality using `setVideoEncodingBitRate()` in `MediaRecorder`.

```
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
```

**mRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(4000000);**`