# Video quality Android:

Tags: android, android-video-player, android-videoview

I have using Video camera by the following code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        Uri videoUri = Uri.fromFile(output_video_storage);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 120);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_VIDEO_CAPTURE_MODE);
```

My problem is now the size of the video is too large i want to reduce the size. I read some documents it said that `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);` here 0 for low quality and 1 for high quality. But i don't think it's working. Both 0 and 1 will no effect.

This question is ask for multiple times in stackoverflow. But no possible answers. Please anyone help me.

Comment: See related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581017/android-modifying-recorded-video-quality and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227119/android-is-there-a-way-to-define-the-video-resolution-when-taking-video-from-a

Comment: IN both 2 questions they use custom camera i need native camera using intent

Comment: @Amsheer did you get anything for that?

Comment: @SyedaZunairah Really no