# reduce video size and quality in android

Tags: android, video

I need to upload video(captured from camera) in my app. but the size of the video am getting from my Xperia is too large(approx. 22 mb for 8 seconds video).Is there any way to reduce size of video. Need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should capture the video in lower resolution.  Here's a link to the answer I provided to a similar question some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227119/android-is-there-a-way-to-define-the-video-resolution-when-taking-video-from-a/11227402#11227402

Comment: @Aleks so what the optimum values for all these variables so that video size get reduced but not degrading the quality too much..??

Comment: I can't tell you what the right values are - you'll need to experiment to find the optimal solution for your needs.  Also have a look at [`getSupportedVideoSizes() `](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedVideoSizes%28%29) call - it will tell you what size video you can record.